Creating an index with a two name description?
I am trying to create an Index in latex with a two name description entry. Such as one for "mass" (one name) and one for "mass, gravitational" (two names) See image below. Can someone help out with this?


Ir would help if you provided some working code that we can use to test solutions. Maybe it works if you treat mass, gravitational as  an index word in the same way as you use mass?

Ok, I'll provide some code.

Ok, this seems to work below:
But the \makeindex command, wasn't working so well, so I needed use:
makeindex index_example_two_names2.idx  

in the terminal. See @ Problem with \printindex. No index created
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Mass\index{Mass} of an object. G etherons may represent the mass\index{mass, graitational!in terms of G etherons} in terms gravity.

\printindex

\end{document}


